# Create a sketch that allows me to run a DC motor and LED sequence at the same time

Tags: programming

I need a program created that will both run a DC motor and an LED sequence at the same time. The image is what the DC motor code should do.

```
/*
-==:: 3 Volts DC Motor Driver with Dual 555 Timer IC ::==-
  * Control Pin from 555 IC is needed to STOP the motor
  * Trigger Pin from 555 IC is needed to drive forward or backward
  * PWM on Trigger Pin is used to set the speed
  * Note : Forward and Backward is interchangeable via Motor connection.
 */

int controlPin = 2; // 555 pinout 5
int triggerPin = 3; // 555 pinout 2

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:

void setup()  { 
  pinMode(controlPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(triggerPin, OUTPUT);
} 

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop()  { 
//  move FORWARD;
    digitalWrite(controlPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH); //full speed
    delay(3000);
//    PWM testing to control motor speed
//    analogWrite(triggerPin, 128+70); //minimum speed (128+70)
//    delay(3000);

//  STOP;
    digitalWrite(controlPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
    delay(3000);

//  move BACKWARD;
    digitalWrite(controlPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW); //full speed
    delay(3000);

//    PWM testing to control motor speed

//    analogWrite(triggerPin, 128-70); //minimum speed (128-70) 
//    delay(3000);

//  STOP;
    digitalWrite(controlPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
}
```

As for the LED code I have no idea. I just found this code on the web. The important thing is that the codes execute at the same time continuously.

Comment: an arduino always runs any program sequentially. ... it's just that it does it so fast, that it looks like it does it at the same time

Comment: I edited the post. I understand that, but what I need is that it continuously runs both things at once... run a dc motor and LED chain.

Comment: `As for the LED code I have no idea` ... what should the LED do? ... you need to have that clearly in your mind, otherwise you cannot write the code

Comment: do not post a picture of your code ... you will not find anybody that is willing to type it into their computer for testing purposes .... put your original text back into your question and format it as code

Comment: Posting pictures of the code is counter productive!

Comment: Edit... Sorry about that didn't think it through. As for the LED I just need them to blink randomly or in an order if its needed. About ten LEDs of different colours.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this yourself? We are not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the Arduino can only execute 1 command at a time. There is no real multi-threading on this hardware. But you can to the work in sequence so fast, that you won't notice the difference with motors or LEDs. Here it is important to use non-blocking code, which doesn't block the execution of other code, when it is only waiting (the `delay()` function is just busy waiting).

For doing anything non-blocking (as setting LEDs or changing the state of a motor) you can use the `millis()` function. Refer to the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example from the Arduino IDE. For a very simple sequence (as blinking) you can directly use the code from the example. Basically you use a timestamp, which holds the last time, the blink code was executed. On every iteration of the `loop()` function you check, if a certain time has passed since the timestamp have been taken. If so, execute the code again and update the timestamp:

```
unsigned long timestamp=0;
void loop(){
  if(millis()-timestamp > 500){
    digitalWrite(led_pin,!digitalRead(led_pin));
    timestamp = millis();
  }
}
```

This code would toggle the led_pin each 500ms.

For coding complex sequences you can make a state machine. For this you create a numeric state variable. In the `loop()` function you use a `switch`-`case`-statement, to execute the right code for each state of your programm. Also directly in the `loop()` function you change the state variable depending on the time through the above code. This would look somewhat like this:

```
int state = 0;
unsigned long timestamp = 0;
void loop(){
  if(millis() - timestamp > 1000){
    state++;
    timestamp = millis();
  }

  switch(state){
    case 0:
      digitalWrite(led_pin,!digitalRead(led_pin));
      //  move FORWARD;
      digitalWrite(controlPin, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH); //full speed
      break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
      digitalWrite(led_pin,!digitalRead(led_pin));
      break;
    case 3:
      digitalWrite(led_pin,!digitalRead(led_pin));
      // stop moving
      digitalWrite(controlPin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
      break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
      digitalWrite(led_pin,!digitalRead(led_pin));
      break;
    case 6:
      digitalWrite(led_pin,!digitalRead(led_pin));
      //  move BACKWARD;
      digitalWrite(controlPin, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW); //full speed
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
      digitalWrite(led_pin,!digitalRead(led_pin));
      break;
    case 9:
      digitalWrite(led_pin,!digitalRead(led_pin));
      // stop moving
      digitalWrite(controlPin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
      break;
    case 10:
    case 11:
      digitalWrite(led_pin,!digitalRead(led_pin));
      break;
    case 12:
      state = 0;
      break;
  }
}
```

This code would toggle the led_pin every second and also doing the moto sequence `3s forward, 3s stop, 3s backwards, 3s stop`. This sequence loops forever.

When you only want to let the led blink continuously, it would be easier to exclude this part of the code from the state machine, but I wanted to show how this principle would work (for example if you want to include a complex blinking sequence).

Comment: I TRIED TO USE THIS CODE BUT AN ERROR SAYS LED_PIN WAS NOT DECLARED IN THIS SCOPE... HAVE ANY IDEA WHAT THAT MEANS?

Comment: Yes, I didn't put in the trivial stuff, because I just wanted to show the working principle. For toggling a pin, you have to define the pin somewhere (for example as global variable). Put in the pin you use for the LED. Also you have to set the pinMode to OUTPUT for this pin in your setup function.     And also don't forget your shift-lock, since you don't have to yell at me :D

Comment: Okay thank you. That helps some, im really new to this language and I am trying to build a DIY project fr an event on Friday. I really don't like to pull all this info out from you, but id greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about that!

Comment: You should read some basic tutorial for Arduino. Also refer to the Blink example from the Arduino IDE. For working further with Arduino you should fully understand, what each command there does, since that are basics (dealing with digital or analog output/input is really important)   And if my answer is good, you may choose it as correct :D

Comment: ahh lol I don't have time... :(